# How do I link an external css to overwrite bootstrap css for centering elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm am having a hard time making websites responsive so i downloaded the basic template and navigation sample from bootstrap, now i'm wondering how do i edit the navigation bar? Because their are already multiple css folders. I tried creating a new css file and editing through there but I can't seem to make it work. What i'm trying to do specifically is making the text centre in the container/wrapper (I'm not sure what exactly it is called, but each word is in a box and i would like to centre the word in that box

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Example</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Work</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">About</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Contact</div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for taking the time to help, have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your custom CSS file is called **after** the Bootstrap CSS:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet " href="yourCustom.css" />
```

Second, add this to your custom css:

```
.col-md-4 {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: In which folder did you add the 'yourcustom.css' file to?

Comment: Okay so the navbar.css is my custom css file that I created. And I added it inside of the css folder which also includes the other bootstrap.css files.

Comment: If you added the css file in your CSS folder, then the path should be ` <link rel="stylesheet " href="css/yourCustom.css" />

Comment: It worked! amazing, thanks very much, now i understand why my css was having no effect. thanks again

Comment: If that's the case, add the text-align code in the navbar.css and change the stylesheet link to ` <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Glad I could help ppinzon :) Do mark this answer as the right one if it helped you in solving the issue

Comment: Good answer, Andrew. +1

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Bootstrap's own structure?

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fam02dzv/)</kbd>

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```